# How to get transaction Status and data regarding that transaction in web3js?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, erc-20, dapps

I have a Dapp where user can buy and send ERC20 token whose bussiness login written in Smart contract..Now when someone buy the token, how do I know in web3 that how much token they've bought and what was their addresss..I intend to use events which was working fine on metamask but not on trust wallet and I want it to be worked on trust wallet..so is there any alternative for events, where I can get the token buyer and the quantity he bought..

Whenever I do transaction, it returns transaction id in return, how do I store that txn Id to use it to be later?? There will be a lot of transactions I guess, so how can I do it safely for the particular address and get it working...

Comment: Hi! Can you please share the code for the buy function in the question? Please also share the code you're using to read the events, and what you mean by it working in MetaMask but not Trust.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you ask how to store a tx id. It seems to me that you understand how to retrieve it, and you can store it as you would store any other information, in a database or similar storage mechanism. Could you explain a bit more what the problem is?